# C# attributecollection.add Apostrophe

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, attributes, html-table

i have a problem.

These are my code lines:

```
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor: pointer;");
row.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("toggle('{0}');", AttributeName));
```

I used it in .Net 2.0 and it worked fine. but now i'm working with .net 4.0 and the Apostrophe 
is converted into `&#39;` in my web page and it doesn't work any more.

How can i still get the Apostrophe itself or bypass this problem??

N.B. it seems to be a [known problem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

Encoding apostropes as `&#39;` is perfectly valid, so it's not your actual problem. Using `onclick="toggle('asdf')"` and `onclick="toggle(&#39;asdf&#39;)"` are equivalent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/FkYut/

You have to look for a different reason why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, when i made find/replace in my source code everything worked fine again... that's why i still assume that this is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

ok... not answer yet... so this was my work around.

```
HtmlGenericControl dynDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

dynDiv = Replace(dynDiv, "&#39;", "'");

public HtmlGenericControl Replace(HtmlGenericControl htmlGenericControl, string    
source, string target)
{
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
     htmlGenericControl.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
     string str = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

     str = str.Replace(source, target);
     htmlGenericControl.InnerHtml = str;

     return htmlGenericControl;
}
```

Small bug - for some reason it duplicates the "div" tag in the ResultPage.aspx but it doesn't interfere the code, so i don't care.

BUT - when i tried to use it for `HtmlGenericControl script = new HtmlGenericControl("script");` it breaks the code. so in this the work around was to implant the actual java script code directly in ResultPage.aspx --> view Designer --> source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    My Script (with the apostrophe...)
</script>
```

Enjoy! :)